# Opening a specific page in Ionic iOs App with FCM push notification

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

FCM push notification works fine on both the devices, the only thing missing is I need to open a specific page once the user clicks on notification, even this functionality works fine on Android devices but on iOs it doesn't' take to the page it just launches the App.

I've included all the certs and fulfilled all other requirements in FCM to make notification work already, I'm on development mode.

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private fcm: FCM,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
      console.log(token);
    });

    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
      console.log(token);
    });
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        console.log('Received in background');
        this.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.id]);
      } else {
        console.log('Received in foreground');
        this.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.id]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

JSON Request 
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Test App",
    "body":"Special Campaign",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "landing_page":"campaign-detail",
    "id":"1034"
  },
    "to":"SAMPLE-TOKEN:APA91bE7JPTYOc4OdSZ50YyY-D2ghOOtfgdUzOYSd0JfNUaiBIDIcnUqzcObT-LzSorX3bplRcYpzrO3C-63fcUt25ZUuonCOlUaYnc7o3iqYcAasdfEdsulZfQy6d-bI58tcj",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

If I click on notification on Android it takes me to desired page but on iOs I get the notification but when I click on it, it just launches the App doesn't take me to the page campaign-detail/1034.

Comment: Hi, after clicking on the notification on Android, how are you redirecting to the details page? Is the details page loading correctly and is it showing all the details that you expect? Can you please share your Ionic code for the same?

Comment: It works, on both the platform
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
{  
 "notification": {
     "body" : "body.",
     "title": "Title",
     "text": "5 to 1",
     "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
     "content_available": 1
   },
   "data" : {
     "landing_page":"campaign-detail",
     "camp_id":"1034"
   },
   "to" : "fA***7-M5GU:************d-bI***twj",
   "priority" : "high"
}

Comment: *************
In app.component.ts I'm using following code inside initializeApp()

this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('User opened a notification ${data}');
        console.log(data.landing_page);
        if (data.wasTapped) {
          console.log('Received in background');
          this.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.camp_id]);
        } else {
          console.log('Received in foreground');
          this.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.camp_id]);
        }
      });

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will give it a try.